# How to remove page numbers and the dotted line from some entries in a "Table of Contents"? - Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I was unable to remove the unwanted `page numbers` and `dotted lines` from the table of contents. I wanna remove the first two numbers. Removing page numbers after adding `page breaks` did not solve it. It still appears in the `table of contents`. How to remove it?

screenshot of the problem is attached here
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! They appear because you set/formatted/styled them as headings.  Set their styles to normal and they won't appear on the table of contents.

Comment: I need the title to appear, but numbers and dotted lines to disappear

Comment: The command to remove page numbers only has to do with page numbers displayed on the actual page. It has nothing to do with what shows up in a Table of Contents. Here is my writing on Page Numbers in Word. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers Using the Forrmat Page Numbers dialog will change how page numbers look (i.e Roman numerals) both on the page and in the Table of Contents. Restarting page numbering in that dialog will also change the numbers on the TOC.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

### In Word, an automatic Table of Contents is a Field. It can be changed using switches in the field.

These are explained in MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm).

First, you can insert a **Custom Table of Contents** and use the options to turn off page numbering. Uncheck the box for page numbers and OK your way out. That way Word sets the necessary switch without you ever having to even see the field coding. This turns off the numbers and dot leader for all entries in the TOC.

[image: dialog box]

If you use this method you may want to add a heading for your Table of Contents like "Contents" or "Table of Contents" using the TOC Heading *Style*.

*(You can also use Fields under the Insert > Quick Parts > Fields series of commands and choosing Table of Contents.)*

If you want to simply change the Field, you would do that by *toggling* the display of Field Codes. In the Windows version that is done with the keyboard shortcut **Alt+F9**. In the Mac version, with **Opt+F9**. On many computers, you need to use the **Fn** key with the shortcuts to activate them.

You will likely see something like `{ TOC \o "1-3" \h \z \u }` when you toggle the display. The same table of contents field without page numbers adds a \n switch to the field: `{ TOC \o "1-3" \n \h \z \u }`. After you add the switch, use the keyboard shortcut to toggle the display of field codes back to showing results. You may need to press **F9** or **Fn+F9** to update the field.

Here is [my article on Dealing With Fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501).
Here is [my writing on the Table of Contents](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Table%20of%20Contents) and the [Table of Contents Gallery](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Word2007TOCGallery).

### Removing Page Numbers from only part of a Table of Contents is trickier. For that, you must modify the field directly.

*To do that, the referenced parts need to be on different levels in the TOC*. This is best done by editing the field. [Suzanne's page goes into this](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm#OmitPageNumbers). This cannot be done using the dialog box.

> **Omitting page numbers for two or more levels**
>
> The field switch used to omit page numbers is the \n switch. Suppose
> you want to have page numbers for just Level 1 and omit them for
> Levels 2 and 3. If you have accepted the default TOC settings, the
> field code you will see when you press Alt+F9 is:
>
> ```
> { TOC \o "1-3" \h \z \u }
> ```
>
> To this field you must add the \n switch followed by the numbers of
> the levels you want to omit page numbers from:
>
> ```
> { TOC \o "1-3" \n 2-3 \h \z \u }
> ```
>
> **Omitting page numbers for a single level**
>
> A much more common requirement, however, is to omit page numbers for
> just Level 1 (especially if the TOC 1 style is centered) and keep them
> for Levels 2 and 3, as shown in Figure 11. You might think that the
> appropriate switch would be “\n 1,” but in fact this won’t work. The
> secret is that the \n switch requires a range of inclusive levels even
> when there’s only one, so the correct field code is:
>
> ```
> { TOC \o "1-3" \n 1-1 \h \z \u }
> ```

---

> **Omitting page numbers for noncontiguous levels**
>
> Suppose you have want to have centered part titles without page
> numbers (TOC 1), chapter titles with page numbers (TOC 2), and some
> other text (subheadings or a blurb like that in Figure 4) without page
> numbers (TOC 3). In other words, you want to omit page numbers from
> TOC 1 and TOC 3 and include them for TOC 2. You can’t have more than
> one \n switch, and there’s no way to include 1–3 without including 2,
> so you might think this can’t be done—and it can’t, at least not that
> way. You just need to be devious!
>
> The trick is to swap styles. You need to use TOC 2 for Heading 1 and
> TOC 1 for Heading 2, and omit page numbers for TOC 2 and 3. In the
> Table of Contents Options dialog, type 2 beside Heading 1 and 1 beside
> Heading 2. Clear the check box for “Outline levels” (because you
> haven’t changed the outline levels of these styles). Insert the TOC,
> then edit the field code to add the \n 2-3 switch. This will give you
> the following:
>
> ```
> { TOC \o "3-3" \n 2-3 \h \z \t "Heading 1,2,Heading 2,1" }
> ```

Quoted material is from [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm#OmitPageNumbers) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill. There is much more there. Again, here is [my article on Dealing With Fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501).